# XMPP Connection keeps getting disconnected android

Tags: android, xmpp, keep-alive

im using a service to keep my xmpp connection active at all times here is the code :

```
public class XMPPService extends Service {


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    new ConnectionStatus().execute();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.i("service", "created");

}
public class ConnectionStatus extends AsyncTask{

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        XMPPClient.getConnection().addConnectionListener(
                new AbstractConnectionListener() {
                    public void connectionClosed() {
                        Log.i("connection", "closed");

                    }

                    public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception e) {
                        Log.i("connection", "closed on error");

                    }

                    public void reconnectionFailed(Exception e) {
                        Log.i("reconnection", "failed");

                    }

                    public void reconnectionSuccessful() {
                        if (XMPPClient.getConnection().isAuthenticated()) {
                            Log.i("isauthenticauted : ", String.valueOf(XMPPClient.getConnection().isAuthenticated()));
                            Log.i("reconnection", "succesful");
                        } else {
                            try {
                                XMPPClient.getConnection().login(new TinyDB(getApplicationContext()).getString("username"), new TinyDB(getApplicationContext()).getString("password"));
                            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (SmackException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Log.i("reconnection", "succesful");
                        }
                    }

                    public void reconnectingIn(int seconds) {
                        Log.i("reconnectingIn", String.valueOf(seconds));
                    }

                }
        );

        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
```

}

but the connection keeps getting disconnected at regular intervals and i get this:

```
 org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException: Parser got END_DOCUMENT event. This could happen e.g. if the server closed the connection without sending a closing stream element
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1148)
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$200(XMPPTCPConnection.java:937)
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:952)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

and after that it starts reconnecting to the server and then i get this :

```
09-07 17:56:03.916  17754-20996/com.sports.unity D/SMACK﹕ SENT (0):            `09-07 17:56:04.217  17754-20997/com.sports.unity D/SMACK﹕ RECV (0): <?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' id='2025993121' from='mm.io' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'><stream:features><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/' ver='Kyn00yB1iXiJLUJ0gVvn7tZREMg='/><register xmlns='http://jabber`
```

how to keep a stable conenction to the xmpp server

Comment: on server side change the property set Client Interval to never disconnect

Comment: it is done but it still keeps dropping  and dosent fully even connect.

Comment: @anupamx Do you got any solution ?

Comment: @anupamx Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This basically happens when your client is idle greater then idle time (“**Idle Connections Policy**”) specified on your server.For this you need to implement **XMPP Ping** classes in your smack/asmack library wherein you have to send **XMPP Pong** as reply to server ping. 
And you could also implement **XMPP reconnection** classes.

Comment: does it mean that we have to periodically keep pinging the server so that the connection stays alive?

Comment: you can increase the 'idle connection time' under Idle Connections Policy and respond back with pong within that time slot or else set client connection as "Do not disconnect clients that are idle" this will keep your client alive until you manually disconnect. Keeping client alive has drawback too such as message loss due to wrong presence(i.e online and offline ).

Comment: @Deepesh  -  I am also working on one chat application and facing the same problem. The thing what you have mentioned here about "Do not disconnect clients that are idle".  How can I achieve to do this?

Comment: @RaviMishra 
Do you guys any solution i am facing same problem, Do you guys got any solution ?

Comment: @arslanhaktic if you are using ejabberd server so will latest version of ejabberd has mod_ping implemented with it. So it will send ping to device and receive pong. Here is the settings for this "mod_ping:
    send_pings: true
    ping_interval: 240"

Comment: @RaviMishra Thanks a lot for your quick response, but i am using openFire for this.